# Show that for any formula $\varphi$ in this language, exactly one of $\varphi$ and $\lnot\varphi$ is a logical consequence of $\Gamma$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose that the language has the set $\{P_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of propositional variables and let $\Gamma$ be the set $\{Q_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $Q_i$ is either $P_i$ or $\neg P_i$ for each  $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that for any formula $\varphi$ in this language, exactly one of $\varphi$ and $\neg \varphi$ is a logical consequence of $\Gamma$.

This question is related to the propositional calculus in mathematical logic, and all theorems and definitions within the propositional logic are allowed to be used.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE, I have edited your question to use LaTeX. You can (and should) learn how to use this for better readability on this website (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). For now, can you also tell us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck? Questions that show effort from the person who asks them are more likely to receive answers (and better answers).

Comment: Well here is what I think, since the set Γ consists of either $P_i$ or $\neg P_i$ then Γ must be consistent. That is for any formula $\varphi$, $\Gamma$ is capable of deriving either it or its negation and by the compactness and soundness theorems, that is equivalent to either $\varphi$ or $\neg \varphi$ to be a logical consequence of $\Gamma$ but not both as the question asks. That's where I'm confused.

Comment: The key point is that there is only one valuation that satisfies $\Gamma$.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main insight is already explained in the comments by Mauro: there is only one valuation that satisfies $\Gamma$ (maybe you know this under a different term, *model*, but for propositional logic we usually call it a valuation).

Let me briefly recall what this means. A *valuation* is a function $v: \{P_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\} \to \{\tt{true}, \tt{false}\}$. This then extends naturally to a function that takes a (propositional) formula as an input and outputs $\tt{true}$ or $\tt{false}$. For a set of formulas $\Gamma$, we say that a valuation $v$ satisfies $\Gamma$ if for every $\phi \in \Gamma$ we have $v(\phi) = \tt{true}$.

So in the situation of your question, the trick is that $\Gamma$ encodes precisely one valuation and that is the only valuation that satisfies $\Gamma$. That is, we define (in the notation of the question):
$$
v(P_i) = \begin{cases}
\tt{true} & \text{if } Q_i \text{ is } P_i \\
\tt{false} & \text{if } Q_i \text{ is } \neg P_i
\end{cases}
$$
By construction $v$ satisfies $\Gamma$, and it is clear that no other valuation can satisfy $\Gamma$. So by soundness and completeness (*not* compactness, as you wrote in your comment) we have that the consequences of $\Gamma$ are precisely the same as the formulas $\phi$ such that $v(\phi) = \tt{true}$. Now the conclusion follows easily: let $\phi$ be any formula, then either $v(\phi) = \tt{true}$ or $v(\phi) = \tt{false}$, in the latter case we have $v(\neg \phi) = \tt{true}$. So either $\phi$ or $\neg \phi$ is a consequence of $\Gamma$, but never both.

Comment: Thank you that clarifies things now. And yeah I did learn the valuation function that you mentioned, we called it a truth assignment, but everything follows now, once again thanks.

Comment: @DiaeMizou If this solves your question, can you accept the answer? That way other users can see that the question has been resolved.

Comment: Done, sorry about that, I'm new to this site.